# store.getState is not a function Redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation, redux-persist

I'm trying to implement Redux-persist on my React Native app. Following the [setup docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) exactly, I changed my store.js from this:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import * as thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from '../reducers';

let middlewares = [thunkMiddleware.default];
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

export default store;
```

To this:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import * as thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import reducers from '../reducers';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

let middlewares = [thunkMiddleware.default];

export default () => {
    let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
    let persistor = persistStore(store);
    return { store, persistor };
};
```

But now, I'm getting the error `TypeError: store.getState is not a function (In 'store.getState()', 'store.getState' is undefined)`.

Note: I've checked out many questions on stackoverflow with the same store.getState error, but they have very specific issues different from my setup.

Edit: Provider implementation (using RNNv2)

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from '../../shared/redux/store';
import { registerScreens } from '../view/screens';
import { initialize } from './navigation';

/**
 * Register screens and components for react native navigation
 */
registerScreens({ store, Provider });


const app = () => {
  Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
    initialize();
  });
};

export default app;
```

Registerscreens:

```
const registerComponentWithRedux = (redux: any) => (
  name: string,
  component: any,
) => {
  Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux(
    name,
    () => component,
    redux.Provider,
    redux.store,
  );
};

export function registerScreens(redux: any) {
  registerComponentWithRedux(redux)(screen, screen.default);
  ...
}
```

Comment: show your code involving `<Provider>`

Comment: Edited. I'm using RNNv2, so I don't use a direct <Provider> component, but use the provider to register my screens.

Comment: I am not familiar with react-native-nav, but when you import store, you are importing the exported function, then passing it into `registerScreens({ store, Provider });`, but `store` is not the output of `createStore` its a function call that returns an object with keys store and persistor

Comment: hard to follow a 100% tho, b/c I can't see file names, try `registerScreens({ store: store().store, Provider });`

Comment: It worked (store().store) - thanks! Do you want to put that in an answer?

Comment: glad it worked, it may have cleared the error, but I think you will have more bugs down the road, I would suggest looking into more code around `react-native-navigation` and `redux-persist` together, try to work in `PersistGate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with the export, you are exporting a function that returns store in a key. So if you update the store reference in register screens it will work.

```
import returnStoreAndPersistor from '../../shared/redux/store';

const {store} = returnStoreAndPersistor();
registerScreens({ store, Provider });
```

Answer (score 0):

If u use 'redux-persists' and return{store, persistor} from ../store just try THIS!!!!!

```
import returnStoreAndPersistor from "../../store";

const { store } = returnStoreAndPersistor()
console.log(store.getState())
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this issue & is using Typescript where the only property on "getState()" is "_persist", the problem was for me caused by setting the type of your combined reducers to "any" due to the type error on supplying your store to persistStore:

`Type AnyAction is not assignable to type {your action type}`

When I fixed the above issue, the getState issue was resolved.

I fixed this by doing this:

```
const _ = (state: any = 0, _: AnyAction) => state;
const root = combineReducers({
    _,
    applicationStatusReducer,
    ...
});
```

It seems to resolve the issue (albeit in a hacky / not actually resolving the underlying issue kind of way), if you just add an empty reducer with the action type of "AnyAction" to it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening because this export default method instead of doing this you
can do it like this.

```
export let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware));


export let persistor = persistStore(store);
```

sorry for any inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

```
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

and then

```
import { store, persistor } from '../../shared/redux/store';
```